# Bibliography: letter after year when there are more than two authors

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, texshop, bibdesk

I'm having some minor issues with those bibliography entries which contain three authors or more:

- in the bibliography itself, it automatically adds a letter after the year (i.e. 1993b), even though it's the only publication with that author in that particular year (so no risk of name conflict) in the main text it does;
- in the text where I cite (`\citealt`) the publication, it doesn't display the shorthand for the citation (LastName 1993), but only the same letter it adds automatically after the year in the bibliography at the end.

To work around the second issue, I just use \nocite and then type the citation manually, but what annoys me is the first issue in particular.

It happens systematically only with entries with more than two authors or editors, and never with one or two.

If it can help: I'm using a Mac with TexShop 3.50 and BibDesk 1.6.5 and compiling with XeLaTeX and BibTex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you use? Please post specific examples of entries whose citation call-outs and formatted bibliography items are giving you problems.

Comment: Thanks. I use a custom style based on apalike.

`@book{Bonfil:2012,
 Booktitle = {Jews in Byzantium},
 Editor = {Robert Bonfil and Oded Irshai and Guy G. Stroumsa and Rina Talgam},
 Publisher = {Brill, Leiden - Boston},
 Year = {2012}}

@book{Feraboli:1996,
 Booktitle = {Manilio. Il Poema degli astri (Astronomica)},
 Editor = {Simonetta Feraboli and Enrico Flores and Riccardo Scarcia},
 Publisher = {Fondazione Lorenzo Valla - Arnoldo Mondadori Editore},
 Title = {Manilio. Il Poema degli astri (Astronomica)},
 Year = {1996}}
`

In the BibDesk preview they're displayd correctly as: Bonfil et al.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce any of the problems you report, using the basic `apalike` bibliography style and the `natbib` package without any options. With which options do you load the `natbib` package? Separately, could the "custom style based on apalike" be messed up? A different topic: both bib entries you've listed have significant errors. For instance, the first entry should use the field `title`, not `booktitle`, and the second entry seems to omit the author of the piece, viz., Marco Manilio, and for some reason inserts the author's name into the `booktitle` field. Do avoid such errors.

Comment: Regarding the bibliography style, I'll try to see if I find something relevant in the code of the .bst generated by the procedure which lets you define your style after asking questions. 

The `booktitle` issue: it's automatically generated by BibDesk, while the name of the author left blank and put it in the title was made on purpose in order not to have "Manilio 1996" in the citation and bibliography, which looks wrong to me.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Regarding the second bib entry: My point was that "Manilio" is the `author` of the piece; I don't understand why he should be listed in the `title` field at all.

Comment: Because if I put it where it's supposed to be, i.e. in the `author` field, it will be quoted as "Manilio 1996", looking as if Manilius wrote his _Astronomica_ in 1996.

I know it's less than ideal, but I want the entry to look like "Feraboli 1996", as it's common practice.

Maybe I could simply remove "Manilio" entirely, so it would be more correct.